# Java. Convert time in EDT, CDT, CST etc. timezones to UTC based on the name of timezone

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

I have API that returns time and timezone separate

```
time: "2018-12-18 16:00:28"

timezone: "EDT"
```

How could I parse it to time in UTC?

Timezones that returns from API: EDT, CDT, CST, EST etc.

I try to find the solution in Java libraries `java.time` and `java.util.TimeZone` but they don't work with some of this timezone names.

Comment: Those three-letter short names are notoriously non-unique.IST can be Israel Standard Time or Indian Standard Time, etc., so you can get unexpected results.

Comment: You are right that is an awful idea to send timezone in such way, unfortunately, I cannot change the legacy system.

Comment: By CST, for example, do you want Australian Central Time, North American Central Time, Cuban Standard Time or China Standard Time? If the time is in the daylight part of the year, du you want daylight time or do you still want standard time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate your strings together so that they can be parsed together. You can then parse into a [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) before changing the zone to whatever you want.

```
String timestamp = "2018-12-18 16:00:28";
String zone = "EDT";
String timeWithZone = timestamp + ' ' + zone;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
    .appendLiteral(' ')
    .appendPattern("z") // Zone
    .toFormatter();

ZonedDateTime edt = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeWithZone, formatter);
ZonedDateTime utc = edt.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC"));
```

Comment: There's also `ZoneOffset.UTC`

Comment: On my Java 9 this gives America/New_York for both EST and EDT, and SystemV/CST6CDT for both CST and CDT. You may want to check if this is as desired. You may also want to validate that you don’t get EDT with a date in the winter or CST with a date in summer, for example. To validate: format the `ZonedDateTime` back using the same formatter and see if you get the same string again.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse it as `LocalDateTime` then set `TimeZone` mannully:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime localDateTime= LocalDateTime.parse("2018-12-18 16:00:28", formatter);
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = localDateTime
        .atZone(ZoneId.of("EST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS))
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS));
```

Comment: I suggest `ZoneId.of("EST", ZoneId.SHORT_IDS)`so you avoid the outdated `TimeZone` class (result will be the same). And `ZoneOffset.UTC` in the following line (will work).

Comment: This solution works only for few of timezones. For EDT I get the exception "Unknown time-zone ID: EDT"

Comment: @OlesiaIlchuk That’s true. You will need to populate the map passed to `ZoneId.of` with the time zone abbreviations you need. `SHORT_IDS` can be a starting point, but doesn’t contain the summer time (DST) versions. What you get in return is full control over how the abbreviations are interpreted. I should think that this is crucial.